# Execution of C program freezes when i create two pipes?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I am trying to create a two way communication between processes (Parent <---> Child).
I writted this code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    printf("Program started.");
    int p1[2]; // CHILD => PARENT
    int p2[2]; // PARENT => CHILD

    if (pipe(p1) < 0) {return -1;}
    if (pipe(p2) < 0) {return -1;}

    int pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {return -2;}
    if (pid == 0)
    {//child process
        close(p1[0]);
        close(p2[1]);

        int x;
        if (read(p2[0], &x, sizeof(x)) == -1) {return 3;}
        printf("Recieved %d\n", x);
        x *= x;
        if (write(p1[1], &x, sizeof(x)) == -1) {return 4;}
        printf("Wrote %d\n", x);

        close(p1[1]);
        close(p2[0]);
    }
    else
    {//parent process
        close(p1[1]);
        close(p2[0]);

        int y = 7;
        if (write(p2[1], &y, sizeof(y) == -1)) {return 5;}
        if (read(p1[0], &y, sizeof(y)) == -1) {return 6;}
        printf("Result is %d\n", y);

        close(p1[0]);
        close(p2[1]);

        wait(NULL);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

This code compiles successfully with gcc on Linux Ubuntu.
When i try to run the compiled file, it freezes. The thing that bothers me is that not even the first printf line is executed:

[image]

if i comment out either of those two lines, code compiles and executes successfully:

```
if (pipe(p1) < 0) {return -1;}
if (pipe(p2) < 0) {return -1;}
```

[image]

(The number is not send successfully between the processes becouse there is only one pipe created, but it runs successfully)

What is the problem, and what am i doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `stdout` (`printf`) is line buffered, so you might not see the line, because you didn't put a `\n` at the end.

Comment: Add print calls between each line of code, ensuring that the messages end with a newline.  Check the result of every system call.

Answer (score 3):

You misplaced a `)` here:

```
        if (write(p2[1], &y, sizeof(y) == -1)) {return 5;}
```

`sizeof(y) == -1` evaluates to 0. so you end up with `write( ... , ... , 0)` so you write nothing.

Comment: Well spotted, sir!

Comment: There is a case to be made that the I/O tests such as `if (read(p2[0], &x, sizeof(x)) == -1)` would be better written as `if (read(p2[0], &x, sizeof(x)) == sizeof(x))` because 0 (indicating EOF) and any value shorter than the size of `x` also indicates a problem.  This applies to both `read()` and `write()`.  The chances of it making a difference in this code is negligible.  In bigger programs, perhaps communicating over a network, such issues can become problems.